# Clear DNS cache of Android Device using Command Line

Tags: android, dns, flush, rooted-device, ndc

I want to flush the system cache of rooted Samsung S7 device using command line. I have been trying ndc resolver but it is giving error "resolver is not a command". Is there any way one can clear the cache of the system using command line.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer... anyway, if you have Chrome installed, go to: chrome://net-internals/#DNS, then click the "Clear host cache" button.